# Microsoft Cognitive Translator API - get actual number of charcter

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am using the free plan of the Microsoft Cognitive Translator Text API (2M charceters per month). Is there a way to get the current status of my plan: how many characters left for the current month?

Before migrate to the azure version of the API, i used to get data on this endpoint: `https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Services/My/Datasets`

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can view your usage for items from the "Overview" of the Azure resource in question.

1. Sign in Azure
2. Click "All resources" icon and select the resource in question
3. "Overview" should be pre-selected and automatically bring up the information you are seeking.

[image]